# Git - error track remote when push project

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I add remote server to exist project, with:

```
git remote add origin git@framagit.org:masoud92m/new-project.git
```

when i use `git push -u origin master` my project uploaded but i get this error:

```
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

why this happen? how i can fix this ?

Comment: Did you verify the remote? Try git remote -v

Comment: i try git remote -v, this only show origin fetch and push url @Passe

Comment: Did you also try the equivalent git set upstream command?

Comment: i'm so sorry, i edited my question, please look again.

Comment: i find `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` in web, but this has error `fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.`

Comment: Try to use just a git push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown text:

> Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Is no error message. But if you just use `git push` without `-u origin master` the text will disappear.

[image]